# Utizando API youtube android

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube-api

Estou a precisar de uma ajuda aqui com youtube android player, alguém me pode ajudar? É a primeira vez que uso .

Por exemplo penso que já adicionei a biblioteca mas  `private YouTubePlayerView youtube;` continua assinalado a vermelho! Se alguém souber como me ajudar agradeço imenso.

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.pt/2013/06/download-and-import-youtube-android.html